# Laravel 5 Function () not found

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm putting together a site which has a protected section where users must be logged in to access. I've done this in Laravel 4 without too much incident. However, for the life of me I cannot figure out why I can't get it to work in Laravel 5(L5).

In L5 middleware was/were introduced. This changes the route file to:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', ['middleware'=>'auth','FooController@index']);
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','FooController@show']);
```

The route works fine as long as the middleware is not included.

When the route is accessed with the middleware however the result is not so much fun.

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> ReflectionException in Route.php line 150:
>
> Function () does not exist

Any insight, help, and/or assistance is very appreciated. I've done the Google circuit and couldn't find anything relevant to my current plight. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

you forgot the `uses` key :

```
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'FooController@show']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something that I just overlooked.

Comment: /**  oh no!! **/

Comment: I just have been struggling with this error for 1 hour. I wrote `user` instead of `uses`. Thank you :p

Answer (score 8):

If you add anything more than your controller method into your routes you need to add `uses` as key of the array for your controller, so for example if I don't haw any middleware it's enough to write:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', 'FooController@index');
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', 'FooController@show');
```

However if you want to add middleware you need to write:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses' => 'FooController@index']);
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses' => 'FooController@show']);
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't use a controller for your view and you just want to display the view, you should do this:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    return View::make('path.to.your.page');
}]);
```